# Gunicorn "error: unrecognized arguments --log-file-"

Tags: python-3.x, heroku, django-rest-framework

I started a Django project and it was working fine in local computer. I deployed it to Heroku and I getting this error:

> 2019-07-06T10:32:11.836364+00:00 app[web.1]: gunicorn: error:
>   unrecognized argum ents: --log-file-
>
> 2019-07-06T10:32:19.185756+00:00 app[web.1]: gunicorn: error:
>   unrecognized argum ents: --log-file-

My `Procfile` contains

```
web: gunicorn tutorial_two.wsgi
```

Answer (score 0):

Gunicorn doesn't recognize the argument `--log-file-`. The `Procfile` you shared with us doesn't contain anything like that, but I'm going to assume that it actually contains something like

```
web: gunicorn tutorial_two.wsgi --log-file-
```

since the error message specifically mentions that argument and this is almost a correct `Procfile` for `Gunicorn`. The problem is that `--log-file` should get an *argument* `-`. Those things shouldn't be attached together.

Modify your `Procfile` to add a space, e.g.

```
web: gunicorn tutorial_two.wsgi --log-file -
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is rather implied. The `gunicorn` program takes the `--log-file -` argument given in the Procfile. May be something like this is the right solution.

```
web: gunicorn tutorial_two.wsgi; --log-file -
```